# Considerations before using the 4 types email templates

Tags: email-template

What are the differences of the 4 email template type (Text, Custom, HTML, Visualforce)? and when should I use them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_templates_classic_types.htm&type=5

To summarize -

**Text** - can contain plain text only - No formating and styling

**HTML with letterhead** - you create letterhead and you use the letterhead for template so that template inherits look and feel of the letterhead.

**Custom HTML** - You can define your own styling with HTML

**Visualforce** - If you want to show data in particular format like table or data is to be fetched from multiple objects then you create visualforce template.

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer maam.